# Where to store data in iOS project?

Tags: ios

I have a part of data that only should be read once. I have ivars in there and want to store them somewhere to have access from my controller. Where should I put it? I'd rather avoid subclassing in this case. My reader should be passing data from some other class, and the other class may be a parent class for something. Am i right?

So my question is: I have some data after my app starts, and where do i have to put it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an array in your appDelegate
then from anywhere:

```
MyAppDelegateClass *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[appDelegate someMethod:..];
```

Comment: This is the way you should **not** solve such issues. Exploiting the app delegate for model data is a big no-no and should be avoided.

Comment: fine Till, it was a quick and dirty solution, I have changed my answer slightly, now app delegate is not exploited

Comment: What is myAppDelegateClass? It's a objective-c regular class (for example NSObject subclass)?

Comment: it is your application delegate class, assuming your application name is XYZ , you should have a file called XYZDelegate.h and .m
just look at your classes, the delegate is there.

Comment: OK, so in my class where i want to use it i should declare this for every object in init method or maybe there is a static way to get this data?

Comment: you can declare it once in the .h MyAppDelegateClass *appDelegate;

and set it once in the viewDidLoad :
appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: Glad to be of service. Nevertheless, as @Till noted, and very rightly so, the deletage is not the place to set large sets of data/logic, since you are calling a small array I don't think it has a major impact on the app, thus my simple&quick solution. you should also read this page for better implementation http://www.cocoanetics.com/2009/05/the-death-of-global-variables/

Answer (score 0):

@ SimpleMan :- Which type of data u have ? Text , Image , Video ?

I think you have text data right ? for text data you can use plist.. or Sqlite database also. Which you want. in this case the data will be store permanently. 
If you want to store data temporary i.e once (existence only in the duration of app running) you can store the data in variables.

in your case while your app is starting you are getting data from server right ? then you should to store that data in application delegate files. i.e AppDelegate.m file.

and use where u want to access. If u have any query then reply me.

Comment: @SimpleMan: Or you can use NSUserDefaults

Comment: Thanks. I have text data like you assumed. But when my apps start i don't know the data yet. I want to store it simply in app. But where? in Array in AppDelegate is a good place?

Comment: @SimpleMan:- yes sure why not ? obvsly you can store in array according to your need. In your case AppDelegate is a good place to store data. and after that you can access by delegate.yourarray method. :-)

Comment: @Till please, post your replay how should i do this

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answers you could just store it in your appDelegate.  If it's not much data then I personally don't see any problem in storing it in the appDelegate.

(I think some people can get too hung up on the "right" or "wrong" way of doing things - if this is a small app and nobody else is going to be working on this app with you then do what's easy as long as your app and your users don't suffer).

If it's lots of data though, or if in future you might want to extend this data significantly I would avoid doing so. In which case, it would be better to create a separate singleton model class to store the data in.